# Class assign in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint, redux-form

Currently I am using `redux-form`, and now I have to connect my `reduxForm` component to my `redux` storage. So, looking at the docs I have to do something like:

```
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(InitializeFromStateForm)

// You have to connect() to any reducers that you wish to connect to yourself
InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }               // bind account loading action creator
)(InitializeFromStateForm)

export default InitializeFromStateForm
```

I did something like that in my component but, `eslint` is giving me an error:

`no-class-asign`

Should I disable this rule for using it with `redux-form` or does exist a way to manage this kind of things?

Comment: I guess instead of using a class declaration you could use a class expression instead: `let InitializeFromStateForm = class extends React.Compeont {}`. But ultimately it's up to you. ESLint lets *you* control the conventions in your code base. If assigning a new value to a "class name" is OK for you, disable the rule.

Comment: Well, in my head I agree with `eslint` but, would it bring me to me some problems, or bugs in the future? I mean, now it is working okey, but nobody knows about the future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need to reassign the class. Why not do something like

```
// Decorate with reduxForm(). It will read the initialValues prop provided by connect()
const reduxFormDecorator = reduxForm({
  form: 'initializeFromState'  // a unique identifier for this form
});

const reduxConnector = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.account.data // pull initial values from account reducer
  }),
  { load: loadAccount }               // bind account loading action creator
);

export default reduxConnector(reduxFormDecorator(InitializeFromStateForm));
```